# Getting final URL with a URL that redirects using Python

Tags: python, spotify

The Spotify API sends you back a URL when authenticating. This URL, redirects you to a previously specified redirect URI (in my case http://localhost:5000) with some parameters that I am after. But so far I can only get to this final URL if I copy paste the URL sent by Spotify into a browser. My question is: how can I obtain this final URL using the redirect URL without a browser, all done only with python.

Obtaining the URL:

```
def authenticate_user():
auth_request = requests.get(ENPOINT_USER_AUTH, {
    'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
    'response_type': 'code',
    'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:5000/',
    'scope': 'playlist-modify-private'
})
```

The result URL:

```
https://accounts.spotify.com/es-ES/login?continue=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.spotify.com%2Fauthorize%3Fscope%3Dplaylist-modify-private%26response_type%3Dcode%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A5000%252F%26client_id%3D3adbd9e...1a42dccff57
```

Copy-paste into browser I get a new URL:

```
http://localhost:5000/?code=AQAVgnC8cnqQ....tnLd4dKlU
```

How can I obtain this final URL just with code? No browsers involved?

Some posts mention urllib, but I have tried to

```
result= urllib.request.urlopen(auth_request.url)
```

And it returns the same exact URL.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: If you're asking can you skip a step in authentication, that depends. The first url might have set up some cookies or headers that you need to get to the second url, especially if it's part of authentication. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I get a 303 code and in the history there is a new URL but not the one I am after. I have tried to make a request to this new URL but I get the exact same URL back.

Comment: yeah, all the 300's are redirect codes of one flavor or another. If the authentication url isn't giving the response you expected, there's something missing from headers, cookies, or your actual credentials. I can't really speculate on a specific server.